# CodeIgniter if...else statement not properly executing

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

`($row->status == "Pass")` should be equaling to true, but for some it isn't. I'm guessing I have code error's. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

```
public function logsig() {
        header('Content-type:application/json');
        $postedUser = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $hashedPass = $this->encrypt->sha1($password);
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$postedUser}' AND password = '{$hashedPass}'");
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                $row = $query->row();
                if ($row->status == "Pass") {
                    $this->session->set_userdata('logged', "1");
                    $this->session->set_userdata("username", "{$postedUser}");
                    echo json_encode(array('session_state' => true));
                } elseif ($row->status == "Fail" || $row->status == "Pending") {
                    echo json_encode(array('session_state' => false));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the value of `$row->status`?

Comment: The row's that I am calling have 'Pass'. But I have other rows with other values such as 'pending' and 'approved'. I'm gonna rid my table of rows that have 'status' values of that different to 'Pass' and see what it does.

Comment: Hmm, it worked, so what does that mean? What's going wrong?

Comment: It's case-sensitive - is it definitely "Pass" in both places? The problem is almost certainly going to be a simple gotcha, so re-check your basics.

Comment: Okay yeah its working. That's weird. thanks man for the help!

Comment: @Joe you should submit an answer to this since you were correct.

Comment: @Henesnarfel From the OPs post I assumed it was something simple, but not the capital P heh. Either way, it's unlikely to be useful for future reference for anyone, because it's just a "re-check your assumptions" problem :)

Comment: @Joe but without an answer this keeps showing up in the unanswered area.  So you should answer or the OP should delete the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copied in from a comment so this doesn't keep showing up in unanswered for Henes :)

---

It's case-sensitive - is it definitely "Pass" in both places? The problem is almost certainly going to be a simple gotcha, so re-check your basics.